# Global section of $\mathcal{O}_X(2)\otimes \Omega_{X/A}$ for $X=\mathbb{P}^1_A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X=\operatorname{Proj}A[X,Y]$ be the projective line over a ring $A$. On $D_+(X)$ we have the section $d(Y/X)$ and similarly we have the section $d(X/Y)$ on $D_+(Y)$. According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/243622/363120), the relation $(X/Y)^2 d(Y/X)=-d(X/Y)$ on $D_+(X)\cap D_+(Y)$ implies that $(X/Y)^2 d(Y/X)$ is a global section of $\mathcal{O}_X(2)\otimes \Omega_{X/A}$. How is that?

We have $\Gamma(D_+(X),\mathcal{O}_X(2)\otimes \Omega_{X/A})\cong X^2d(Y/X) A[Y/X]$, so $X^2d(Y/X)$ defines a section over $D_+(X)$. Similarly, we have the section $Y^2d(X/Y)$ over $D_+(Y)$ and we cannot quite glue them due to the sign. Anyway, this doesn't seem to make sense of $(X/Y)^2 d(Y/X)$ defining a global section.